# In WireShark, how can I filter results so that it shows only a single line per source?

Tags: wireshark

I'm using WireShark to find any systems pointed to an old system we're decommissioning and rather than showing the same IP 1,000 times I'd like to use a filter that will only show each IP source once.

Can somebody tell me how I can go about doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the statistics menu](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseStatisticsMenuSection.html#ChUseWiresharkStatisticsMenu):
- [Conversations](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatConversations.html#ChStatConversationsWindow)
- [Endpoints](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatEndpoints.html#ChStatEndpointsWindow)
- IP Addresses…
You can find more information in [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Statistics).

Answer (score 1):

This is a breeze from the command line if you have linux or cygwin (IP 1.2.3.4 is the old system):

```
tshark -nr file.pcap -Tfields -e ip.src -Y "tcp.flags==2 and ip.dst==1.2.3.4" | sort | uniq
```